# php mysqli prepared statement in nested loop throwing command out or sync error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following function which has both for and while loop to execute a prepared statement. But it is throwing error as `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Here is my function

```
public function queryProductDetail() {

    $product_info = $this->mysqliengine->prepare("select product_id, sku from product limit 10");
    $product_info->execute();
    $product_info->bind_result($product_id,$sku);

    $product_image = $this->mysqliengine->prepare("insert into product_image(product_id,thumb_image,medium_image,original_image) values(?,?,?,?)") or die($this->mysqliengine->error);
    $product_image->bind_param('isss',$api_product_id, $thumb_image, $medium_image, $original_image);


    while($product_info->fetch()) {
        $rowResult = $this->api->queryProduct(array('serverParams' => array('sku' => $sku, 'usertoken' => USER_TOKEN)));
        foreach($rowResult->result->imagesUrls->Image as $image) {
            $api_product_id = $product_id;
            $thumb_image = $image->smallurl;
            $medium_image = $image->middleurl;
            $original_image = $image->bigurl;
            $product_image->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me why this is happening.

This is the message `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` in `$product_image->bind_param`

Answer (score 0):

### [C.5.2.14. Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)

> This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result(). It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

`$product_info->execute()` opens a mysql resource which prevents a new query. [Unbuffered Queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) might be a cause for that error. [`mysqli_stmt::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) returns unbuffered results by default:

> Prepared statements return unbuffered result sets by default. [..] It is also possible to buffer the results of a prepared statement using [`mysqli_stmt_store_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php).

Comment: I cant get what do you mean

Comment: If I use fetch_all gettting error as `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all()`